# Click on a javascript element with Watir/Selenium/anything

Tags: javascript, ruby, watir, custom-component

[image: When Opened]

[image: When Closed]

The first one is when I open it up and select a value, and the second one is when I haven't selected a value and it is closed. It appears to only change the `<span class="va-sm-m">Size</span>` tag, there are no other elements on the webpage related to this, and everything appears to be in this one component. They must be using like React/vue/etc. It is just a simple dropdown grid with a bunch of different sizes. Only the dropdown is actual html, all the options to select are not on the webpage during opening either. How would I select this. I already consulted the watir Slack, to no avail.

Comment: Any chance this is on a public page (ie to make it easier to reproduce the problem)?

Comment: Try doing things like `document.querySelector('[data-qa="dropdown-container"]').click()` in your browser console

Comment: @JustinKo I have an NDA, so I cannot disclose the website :/